Using beamer to create an article-like presentation
The question might sound confusing but what I am trying to achieve is a similar behavior to what we see in a default article document, but using beamer instead. The goal is to do a presentation as a slideshow, but I find beamer templates considerably a hassle to work with, so I am trying to be able to use commands like \vspace and \hfill to achieve positioning and the default behavior we have when writing in an article document type.
To give an idea of what I mean, consider the following snippet:
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]
\setbeamersize{text margin left = 0cm, text margin right = 0cm}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}{
    \beamer@frametopskip = 0cm\relax
    \beamer@framebottomskip = 0cm\relax
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak = \beamer@frametopskip\relax
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak = \beamer@framebottomskip\relax
}
\beamer@centeredfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Top text
        \vfill
        Center text
        \vfill
        Bottom text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


This almost achieves what I am looking for, except that there is still some padding on the top and bottom.
Another weird behavior is when I add \hrule before the Top text line. It makes my text shift up exactly how I expect it to be, but the same can not be said about the bottom text.
Any help would be appreciated on this matter and, at this point, I am also considering if it is useful to use the beamer document type or if it is worth using a standalone and defining stuff the way I want.
Thanks in advance!

could you be a bit more specific? which behaviour from article are you trying to achieve in beamer? could you also please explain what this is for? presentations and articles are very different documents, so it is a bit hard to understand the motivation behind this without something a bit more concrete.

To get rid of the space at the top: \begin{frame}[s]         \nointerlineskip         Top text

@cfr yes, I edited my question to add more emphasis. I'm trying to do a presentation but I find beamer a bit difficult to work with when you don't want to use templates.

Are you sure placing content at the very bottom of the slide is a good idea? I would usually top align any content which minimises the risk of the head from the person sitting in front of you obscuring parts of the content.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I am not really trying to place something on the bottom, I just want to be able to reach the bottom if I'm ever writing a lot in a single slide. Mainly just wanna have it available.

@cfr and also samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you for your personal preference and advice, respectively. There is certainly a lot of irrelevance to both comments, since they don't align with what was asked. If you have any suggestions on how to change the behavior of the beamer frame to what was asked in the original post, I'd be very glad to hear it!

actually, my personal preference would be to pack far more into my slides than beamer encourages. but that's only my preference when I'm writing the presentation rather than watching somebody else's. I know that if I give into that inclination, I will make my slides less intelligible to my audience. so I reduce content or split it across slides or divide and apportion it to different frames. that is, I read the beamer manual's guidance and concluded it is largely right.

why are you using beamer at all? why not just use geometry to set the correct page dimensions and use article?

by the way, there is no 'padding' at the bottom. you would get the same in article with zeroed margins. the spacing between lines allows for descenders. otherwise the baseline of the bottom line of text would depend on the content e.g. if you had 'bottom of page' it would be higher than 'bottom'. if you move the line down, a word such as 'page' would get clipped.

@cfr, I think I'll definitely go down the geometry package solution. Thanks for the suggestion btw! I'll keep this open in case anyone finds a way to set this up in a beamer document.

I suppose what I'm getting at is this: what is it you want from beamer besides the geometry settings? because it looks as if you want to basically undo all the stuff beamer does except for that one thing. if so, it's doubtless better to just not use it. if there's something you want from beamer, that's a different matter, but I'm not clear what that might be?

If you want to place something at the bottom edge, use the footline template.
